# Array of structure - memory release in C

Tags: c, memory-management, data-structures, struct, priority-queue

I am trying to implement a priority queue based on binary heap using a static array (I will be later using a linked list, just wanted to test first with an array).

```
typedef struct n
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int size;
    double value;
} node;

node arr[100];
int total = 1;

void insertElement(int x, int y, int size, double value)
{
    node n;
    n.x     = x;
    n.y     = y;
    n.size  = size;
    n.value = value;

    arr[total] = n;

    if (total > 1)
        insertArrange(total);

    total += 1;
}
```

Now in the delete function i will just return the top most node and delete it, then re-arranging the whole heap. Problem is I can not free any memory. Suppose I use

```
free(&arr[1]);
```

I am getting **pointer being freed was not allocated** error. Is this the proper way of implementation? How to tackle memory issues?

I am using Xcode with Apple LLVM 4.2 compiler. This entire thing will be ultimately put into a bigger project in Objective-C but for now I do not want to use NSMutableArray. I want a simple solution in C.

Comment: You wouldn't free an `int` declared like that. Why free a `node`?

Comment: sorry that line was **free(&arr[1])** which resulted in the error I mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why delete? You could just zero it out and write new data to it whenever you need to. Also My recommendation would be to remember which nodes you delete, so that later when you need to insert a new node, you will know beforehand where the free space is.

For example:

```
node arr[10];
indexes free_index[10];
//(delete the 6th member of nodes)
delete arr[5];
//remember which one you deleted
free_index[0] = 5;
//later when you add new node you can search the index and pick the first matching value
// zero it out so that it will not be used accidentally again like this
int i = free_index[0] // finding which one is free is task for loops
new_node(arr[i]);
free_index[i] = NULL;
```

This code example here is very incomplete you have to complete it depending on your own implementation. I just gave you the idea. watch out for free_index [0] = 0; it basically will never match as a valid index. If you zero out indexes with = NULL statement.

There is also a big assumption from my side that you do not wish to shrink the size of this array or grow it. Just empty some elements and then add new ones.

If you want to grow the array you have to [calloc](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/calloc.html) it first. I advise calloc because you can allocate array of structs with it.

Growing this is easy with [realloc](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/functions/realloc.html).

But with shrinking you need to create temporary array of nodes where you will store all active results, shrink the original array, put the active results from temporary array back into original and free temporary array.

```
calloc(numberofnodearrays,sizeof(node));
```

Comment: Thanks I will be using the calloc and realloc to implement this. But from what you assumed it was wrong, I am using it for a priority queue and suppose I delete the top (delete will always be top - highest priority), the array size shrinks. Another thing to note is that all the insertions will be done at first and then 1 by 1 delete, so I will just figure a workaround like making that element negative etc..

Answer (score 5):

You only need to call free() if you have used malloc() or calloc(). In fact, attempting to free anything else is *undefined behaviour*.

As it stands, your code will not be leaking any memory.

Comment: Ok i get your point. Can you please show me how to implement the delete function? Just return the first element and then delete it. (Rest of the heap let it be intact - I will rearrange later.)

Comment: @Soumyajit, arr[] is stack-allocated; you must not attempt to delete any memory.